# How to run jar file on shell script in linux terminal?

Tags: java, linux, shell

I made a java project.
The project is....output log message and system.out.println message. just simple.
So I changed into a jar file(the name is LinuxSample.jar).
and I wrote a shell script to run this jar file.
Look at this shell script. (speakee is package name and PrintLinux is main class name)

```
#!bin/bash
CLASSPATH=/home/tangooc/TANGOOC/test/libs/*
CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH};/home/tangooc/TANGOOC/test/linux/LinuxSample.jar"
java speakee.PrintLinux
```

this jar file and this shell script work in Window.
but linux didn't work. I don't know why

this is error message.

```
Could not find or load main class
```

Comment: `Could not find or load main class` -> does the class have a main method? is it `public static`? is the class compiled?

Comment: Isn't the usual way to execute java jar archives to use the `-jar` switch on the command line? So simply something like `java -jar LinuxSample.jar`...

Comment: @Arun Yeah it is a main method and already compiled

Comment: @arkascha I added the sentence(java -jar LinuxSample.jar) in shell script. but it didn't work and error message  ---> (Error: Unable to access jarfile LinuxSample.jar )  I think this jar need library. but I already added CLASSPATH library...hum..,,,,

Comment: Sounds like me like you have a path issue, so that you only specified the file name but have your current working directory in another folder. Have a try using the full absolute path or change the working directory in your script.

Comment: Give full main class path

Comment: @Arun /home/tangooc/TANGOOC/test/linux/LinuxSample.jar(PrintLinux main method in speakee package)

Comment: try this: java -jar <your full path>/yourJar.jar

Comment: java -jar command ignores the commands that follow. anyway I made it !! I wrote the solution my commend

Answer (score 0):

Hi Best way to run a java application is to set CLASS_PATH and PATH variable first. If your current jar file depends on external jar files you will face lots of problem. Better set your path variable like below and run the application:-

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
export PATH=/usr/java/bin:$PATH
# =/usr/java/bin is your java bin folder
#set environment variable CP with all the jar libraries
CP=/home/flussi/xmlEncoder/encoder.jar 
CP=${CP}:/other/jar/somejar.jar

java -Xmx256M -classpath "$CP" "com.myproj.Example"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it still didn't work and print error message ---> Could not find or load a main class speakee.PrintLinux

Answer (score 0):

I made it
I changed the shell script.

```
CLASSPATH=/home/tangooc/TANGOOC/test/client/LinuxSample.jar
LIB_TOTAL=/home/tangooc/TANGOOC/test/libs/*
echo ${LIB_TOTAL}
echo ${CLASSPATH}
java -cp ${LIB_TOTAL}:${CLASSPATH} speakee.PrintLinux
```

also there is another way.

```
CLASSPATH=/home/tangooc/TANGOOC/test/client/LinuxSample.jar
CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/home/tangooc/TANGOOC/test/libs/*
echo ${CLASSPATH}
java -cp ${CLASSPATH} speakee.PrintLinux
```

If the someone like me change the shell script.
and check a line, a line, a line...